# How to manage own nuget package per project in the solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

We want to package some third party assemblies into our own nuget package. I created some packages with NuGet Package Explorer, and published it to our nuget server. I can also install it into our solution, however I have two problems:

1. Minor problem: when I install our nuget package a .nuget directory created with a packages.config in it. This contain a reference only to the package I added. We already have however several nuget packages installed into our solution. Every packages is in the packages subfolder in it's own subfolder, plus there's a repositories.config in the packages folder. The repositories config points to other packages.config, but not the one which is created by my actions into the .nuget folder. This is true even if I try to install the nuget package using the console into a specific project!
2. Major problem: When I look up the installed packages in the "Manage NuGet packages for the Solution...", I only see an "Uninstall" button for my package. I expect and want to have a Manage button, same what we have for the other nuget packages, which allows to check/uncheck the package per project in a treeview.

I use latest VS 2012, latest NuGet (2.2.xxx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by incorrect package creation. When you create your package (with NuGet Package Explorer), on the right big "Package Contents" pane you want to create a lib folder by right click and selecting "Add Lib Folder" from the context menu. Then you want to add your assemblies into this folder instead of the root of the package content.
Having the right package structure helped achieving the expected behavior: no .nuget folder is created any more and I can "Manage" my package also.

Comment: If you are not using NuGet Package Explorer, but you create your package at the command line, the structure will be correct. That's how I found out the bug, when I compared a good package with a bad one.

Comment: @MrFox maybe other parts of the package are not align with the expected untold conventions? I'm also not sure if case sensitiveness applies. So you say you still have this problem although the structure seems fine?

Comment: yes that's probably the case, I just don't know any of those conventions.

Comment: I even have nuget packages that can be installed and managed per project, but can't see any difference between them and my current project.

Comment: I'm not active in the project which inspired my SO entry any more, and I'm too busy to just fiddle with some skeletons. Hopefully someone can chip in.

Comment: My advice: look at packages which work well, and try to figure out the difference. That's how I got enlightened. https://docs.nuget.org/Create/Package-Conventions